# Is there a way for me to know when a DAG finished running in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm running a script that checks the status of my database before a DAG runs and compares it to after the DAG finished running.

```
def pre_dag_db
  pass

def run_dag
  pass

def post_dag_db
  pass
```

Is there a way for me to know when the DAG finished running so that my script knows when to run post_dag_db? The idea is that my post_dag_db runs after my DAG finished running because the DAG manipulates the db.

Comment: You **must** handle connections at the Task/Operator Level. And you can trigger python function before or after a task using Airflow callbacks. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964337/2508468

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to just run the script as last task in your dag, maybe using a BashOperator.

Other options would be to trigger a separate dag (TriggerDagRunOperator) and there implement a dag that calls your script.

If you really cannot call your script from Airflow itself, you might want to check the REST APIs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/api.html and use them to retrieve information about the dag_run. But this seems overly-complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way is to add one task in DAG which will work/run as last task of the DAG, this will work like magic for you.

you can use any of the operator like (PythonOperator, BashOperator, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code:

```
dag = get_dag(args)
dr = DagRun.find(dag.dag_id, execution_date=args.execution_date)
print(dr[0].state if len(dr) > 0 else None)
```

This code is taken from [airflow cli](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7bac1296ba47641b5f6fdfdc6a169be1bd20b862/airflow/bin/cli.py#L590).

Answer (score 0):

### Please, don't do it like this

An Airflow task needs to handle resource connection and disconnection itself.

An Operator needs to produce an atomic and repeatable result. Using Idempotence is the way to go.

I invite you to read [Astronomer's Best Practices about DAG design](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dag-best-practices#dag-design)

> When organizing your pipeline into individual tasks, each task should be responsible for one operation that can be re-run independently of the others. In an atomized task, a success in part of the task means a success of the entire task.

and of course you should also read [Airflow Best Practices for creating a task](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#creating-a-task).

> You should treat tasks in Airflow equivalent to transactions in a database. This implies that you should never produce incomplete results from your tasks.

> Airflow can retry a task if it fails. Thus, the tasks should produce the same outcome on every re-run.

### But it's still possible

If you want to risk zombie connections to your DB, then you might want to use these [Airflow Callbacks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.3/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html) for your first and last tasks to initialize and close connections.

- **on_execute_callback** *Invoked right before the task begins executing*
- **on_success_callback** *Invoked when the task succeeds*
- **on_failure_callback** *Invoked when the task fails*

Beware that your connection need to be closed on successes **AND** on failures. If you're using retries, the connection will still be running because of its state being `up_for_retry`.

If the scheduler fails to properly run your DAG, and sometimes strange things happen, then **you'll have zombie connections in your DB**.

```py
EmptyOperator(
    task_id="your_task_id",
    on_success_callback=[post_dag_db],
    on_failure_callback=[post_dag_db])
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a custom class that inherits from dag, and whose dependencies are the same as your dag.

something like (custom_dag.py)

```
from airflow.models.dag import DAG


class PreAndPostDAG(DAG):
    @property
    def tasks(self) -> List[BaseOperator]:
        return [self.pre_graph] + list(self.task_dict.values()) + [self.post_graph]


    @property
    def pre_graph(self):
        #whatever crazy things you want to do here, before DAG starts
        pass

    @property
    def post_graph(self):
        #whatever crazy things you want to do here, AFTER DAG finishes
        pass
```

That's the easiest I can think of, then you just import it when defining your dags:

```
from custom_dag import PreAndPostDAG
with PreAndPostDAG(
    'LS',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    # t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='list',
        bash_command='ls',
    )
```

You get the rest, hope that helps